# Factoring maps of handlebodies

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Any map of finite graphs (1-dimensional CW-complexes) factors as a composition of

1. a finite sequence of folds;
2. an inclusion; and
3. a finite-to-one covering map.

There should be a corresponding result for handlebodies, which presumably should say that, after a homotopy, a continuous map of handlebodies factors as:

1. a compression (by which I mean a map of a handle into the complement of its interior);
2. an inclusion; and
3. a finite-to-one covering map.

Is my intuition correct, and does anyone have a reference?  I'm specifically interested in how well-behaved the homotopy can be taken to be.  For instance, can it be made to respect the boundary?

**Notes**

A *fold* is a map that identifies two edges with a common endpoint.  Many folds don't change the homotopy type of a graph, and one would expect not to need these in the handlebody setting.  The important folds are the ones that kill a loop.  In handlebody terms, you can think of this as gluing in a two-handle, or as cutting a one-handle - hence my use of the word "compression".  Is this word acceptable in this context?

The graph-theoretic result is due to [Stallings](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=RT&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=stallings&s5=finite%20graphs&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=2&mx-pid=695906).

By an *inclusion* of handlebodies, I mean that the new one should be obtained from the old by attaching 1-handles.

**EDIT** (prompted by Sam's comments below) I'm not quite sure what "respect the boundary" should mean, at this point.  Suggestions welcome!

Comment: What does "respect the boundary" mean?

Comment: At each "time", the homotopy should map the boundary to itself.

Comment: So the maps has to start by mapping the boundary to the boundary? For example, what about placing a trefoil knot in a three-ball, and thickening it a bit?  A homotopy can unknot this (and then I guess you want to compress), but not in any boundary respecting way...

Comment: I'd be happy to start with _any_ factorization, and worry about whether the homotopy can be made nice later.

Comment: What about taking a regular neighborhood of the (p,q) curve on the boundary (p times about the meridian, q times about the longitude).  So this is incompressible... I suppose that you will homotope this to be a q-fold covering.  I don't see how you are going to do this keeping the boundary "nice".

Comment: Sam, I see what you mean - I'm a little confused about what the correct statement about the boundary should be.  I realise now that my original comment didn't make sense.  Well, as I said, I'd be happy for *any* factorization to start with, and to worry about the boundary later. 

Comment: Ok, will the following suffice: homotope first, compress second and then realize that the result includes in a finite-index cover?

Comment: (Or does that mess up the desired order?)


Comment: That's exactly the order I had in mind!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that we are given a PL map from a handlebody $W$ to a handlebody
$V$.  Choose a spine for $W$.  Homotope the map until the image is a
regular neighborhood of the image of the spine.  By general position,
our map is now an embedding.  Fix a pants decomposition of disks $D =
(D_i)$, for $V$.  Suppose that $P$ is a component of $V - D$ (so $P$ is a
three-ball with three distinguished disks on its boundary).  Consider a 
component $X$ of $f(W)
\cap P$.  This is essentially a knotted graph.  Via a homotopy (keeping
$X \cap D$ fixed) unknot $X$.  If the rank of $X$ is positive then another 
homotopy produces small lollipops which we shall compress a bit later.
If $X$ meets any disk $D_i \subset \partial P$ more than once 
then we may homotope a leg of
$X$ through $D_i$.  Let $Y$ be the resulting component of $f(W) \cap
P$. (Note that this reduces $f(W) \cap D$.)

Homotoping in this fashion we eventually arrive at an embedding of $W$
so that every component in every three-ball of $V - D$ is either a
tripod or an interval, possibly with lollipops attached.  The feet of
the tripod/interval lie in distinct disks in the boundary of the
containing solid pants.

Now compress all of the lollipops to get $f'(W')$ (a new handlebody,
because we compressed and a new map because we have to extend it over
the two-handles we added).

EDIT:
This reproduces, in our context, part of Stallings paper (eg sliding 
the leg is a fold, arriving at only tripods and intervals produces 
an immersion.)

Since $f'$ is an immersion, it follows from Stallings paper that $f'$ 
is $\pi_1$ injective and that $W'$ embeds into a finite cover of $V$.

Comment: Looks good!  I want to use a homotopy to make X as big as possible in P, so the complement is either empty or a ball whose boundary contains one distinguished disc.  If we do so then I think we get that, after a homotopy, the map factors as: glue on some 2-handles; glue on some 1-handles; and then a finite-sheeted covering.  (Note that, in the question, I mentioned that by "inclusion", I meant gluing on 1-handles.)  Does that sound right?

Comment: (I mean that the complement of X in P should be a ball *after X has been compressed*.)

Comment: This is right.  After producing f' we can 1) isotope each components of $f'(W') \cap D_i$ to be homeomorphic to its containing disk, 2) apply isotopy extension to the map $f'$, and 3) fix the boundaries of the components $f'(W') \cap P$. 

Comment: Excellent!  I think this is the best possible statement I could have hoped for.